Length of base-pairing required in Argonautes
I've been reading a lot about Argonautes and its recognition mechanism and how there are some differences on how they match the target RNA.
I know that the (mi)RNA guides are quite longer than what is used to match the target.
The seed region is relatively conserved (nt g2–g7 or g2–g8), and there are some papers that define a supplementary region (g13–g16), but I did not find a consensus on that.
Are there resources about which nucleotides are really needed to pair with the target in different Argonautes? I am mostly interested in mammalian vs plant Argonautes.
I am not really interested in the dynamics, just the number of nucleotides needed to match the target (and how performance degrades with mismatches).
